# How do I change a column I created a while ago in sql to foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to change multiple tables to foreign keys. I have used the command

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions
ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES transaction_id(item_rental_id);
```

The table name was financial_transactions and the column name was item_rental_id. It gives me an error saying:

> Foreign key 'FK__financial__item___46E78A0C' references invalid table 'transaction_id'.

How do I resolve this?

[image: Structure]

Comment: The target of a foreign key needs to be a primary key.

Comment: transaction_id is the primary key. Is there any syntax error? Thanks

Comment: references invalid table 'transaction_id' meaning there is no transaction_id table

Comment: you have to map the table where the item_rental_id will be referencing from

Comment: Read this article about foreign key concept https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. For this example, SalesOrderHeader would be your financial_transactions table and SalesPerson would be the table where the foreign key would refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give second table name
both way can do it
1. Add reference without name

```
 ALTER TABLE financial_transactions
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES customer_rentals(item_rental_id);
```

2.Add reference with a name

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Financial_Transactions_Customer_Rental_Item_Rental_ID
   FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES Customer_rentals(item_rental_id);
```

Comment: where did you get the item_rental table? did you just assume based on the naming convention?

Comment: That is what I guess second table name Item_rental based on column name item_rental_id

Comment: It won't work because there is no item_rental. The table which contains the column is financial_transactions and the primary key column is transaction_id. I need to add foreign key to item_rental_id column

Comment: If you want to add foreign key to item_rental_id, it has to been in another table, you use transaction_id as second table will not working. Are you sure you want to add foreign key not index?

Comment: as I've said on my comment on your question, you have to find the table where you want to make reference to the item_rental_id

Comment: I think I got your point. I am very new to sql. item_rental_id is in a table called customer_rentals where I have defined it as the primary key. I believe this is the table that you are talking about.

Comment: ALTER TABLE financial_transactions
ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES customer_rentals(item_rental_id);  I am getting a new error now he ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__financial__item___4BAC3F29". The conflict occurred in database "tvk5250", table "dbo.customer_rentals", column 'item_rental_id'

Comment: Yes, that will works, and make sure item_rental_id is primary key in customer_rentals table. When you make foreign key, please use some standard name convention, I will use FK_Financial_Transactions_Customer_Rentals_Item_Rental_ID

Comment: Yes @TonyDong it is the primary key in customer_rentals table but I am still getting this error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__financial__item___4BAC3F29". The conflict occurred in database "tvk5250", table "dbo.customer_rentals", column 'item_rental_id'

Comment: How do you make accountID as foreign key, you can do the same with item_rental_id

Comment: This is because the data in financial_transactions table with item_rental_id does not exist in customer_rentals table.

Comment: I used this command ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD CONSTRAINT
fk_financial_transactions_accounts FOREIGN KEY(account_id)
REFERENCES accounts (account_id);

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, I also modify my answer, please see the update code.

Comment: Using your new answer @TonyDong, I am getting this error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Financial_Transactions_Customer_Rentals_Item_Rental_ID". The conflict occurred in database "tvk5250", table "dbo.customer_rentals", column 'item_rental_id'.

Comment: I guess the reason is in your financial_transactions table, some value in item_rental_id not exists in customer_rentals table, could you double check the value? May be some null value in financial_transactions table?

Comment: That's what I am saying.

Comment: Ferdinand, we are on the same way now, but why I am still get down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a correct script to create a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES customer_rentals(item_rental_id);
```

However, if you are trying to add a foreign key constraint on a table with data already in it, you have to make sure that the item_rental_id in financial_transactions table are also in the customer_rentals table. Otherwise, you will have a referential integrity error.

To illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_rentals_1
(item_rental_id INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (item_rental_id)
);

CREATE TABLE financial_transactions_1
(transaction_id INT,
 item_rental_id INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions_1
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES customer_rentals_1(item_rental_id);
```

The scripts above will run successfully.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_rentals_2
(item_rental_id INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (item_rental_id)
);

CREATE TABLE financial_transactions_2
(transaction_id INT,
 item_rental_id INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);

INSERT INTO financial_transactions_2
VALUES (1000, 9999);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions_2
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (item_rental_id) REFERENCES customer_rentals_2(item_rental_id);
```

But, this will have the following error since item_rental_id 9999 is not present in customer_rentals_2 table

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 31
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__financial__item___76969D2E". The conflict occurred in database "TESTDB", table "dbo.customer_rentals_2", column 'item_rental_id'.
```